# Preview do Android Studio não está sendo exibido

Tags: android, api, layout, gradle

Estou tendo problemas ao importar um projeto que foi escrito numa versão mais antiga do Android Studio. Meu preview não aparece. Sou iniciante e gostaria de uma ajudinha! Segue o gradle e o xml. A activity está padrão, só tem o onCreate, no emulador a aplicação roda normal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.miwok"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

}

Comment: Altere de theme na opção "Select Theme"

Answer (score -1):

A ConstraintLayout é um ViewGroup que permite posicionar e dimensionar widgets de maneira flexível.

Não esta no seu Código xml. Deveria estar onde vc colocou o comentário e o fechamento no final do código.

Comment: Não estou usando ConstraintLayout, não precisa ainda...